# How to pass context in odoo9?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to pass the partner_id which is selected in sale order to pricelist via context how to do that ?

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('product_id')
def product_id_change(self):
    if not self.product_id:
        return {'domain': {'product_uom': []}}

    vals = {}
    domain = {'product_uom': [('category_id', '=', self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id)]}
    if not self.product_uom or (self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id != self.product_uom.category_id.id):
        vals['product_uom'] = self.product_id.uom_id

    product = self.product_id.with_context(
        lang=self.order_id.partner_id.lang,
        partner=self.order_id.partner_id.id,
        quantity=self.product_uom_qty,
        date=self.order_id.date_order,
        pricelist=self.order_id.pricelist_id.id,
        uom=self.product_uom.id
    )

    name = product.name_get()[0][1]
    if product.description_sale:
        name += '\n' + product.description_sale
    vals['name'] = name

    self._compute_tax_id()

    if self.order_id.pricelist_id and self.order_id.partner_id:
        vals['price_unit'] = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price(product.price, product.taxes_id, self.tax_id)
    self.update(vals)
    return {'domain': domain}

@api.onchange('product_uom', 'product_uom_qty')
def product_uom_change(self):
    if not self.product_uom:
        self.price_unit = 0.0
        return
    if self.order_id.pricelist_id and self.order_id.partner_id:
        product = self.product_id.with_context(
            lang=self.order_id.partner_id.lang,
            partner=self.order_id.partner_id.id,
            quantity=self.product_uom_qty,
            date_order=self.order_id.date_order,
            pricelist=self.order_id.pricelist_id.id,
            uom=self.product_uom.id,
            fiscal_position=self.env.context.get('fiscal_position')
        )
        self.price_unit = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price(product.price, product.taxes_id, self.tax_id)
```

here

```
vals['price_unit'] = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price(product.price, product.taxes_id, self.tax_id)
```

i want to pass the partner_id context so i can check if a specific Bool is True or false and do the computation according to it.

when i pass the context it says this accepts 4 and i have given 5.
now where do i change this so it takes 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since new API context is encapsulated in an environment object, which often can be called like `self.env`. To manipulate the context just use the method `with_context`. An simple example:

```py
vals['price_unit'] = self.env['account.tax']\
    .with_context(partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id.id)\
    ._fix_tax_included_price(
        product.price, product.taxes_id, self.tax_id)
```

For further information look into the [Odoo Doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#environment)

Comment: please tell me how i can fetch/get the partner_id value in _price_rule_get_multi in product.pricelist which is in osv.osv

Comment: it depends on how you've overriden the method. You can override it with old api or with new api. Old api is simple: just use the variable `context`. In new api calls, you can find the context under `self.env.context`.

Comment: i am doing vals['price_unit'] = self.env['account.tax']\
    .with_context(partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id.eqp_card) still it is passing the id .....i tried changing the partner_id to something else then it passes None.

Comment: Or is there any way i can check the eqp_card column from the id i get in pricelist.

Comment: this is eqp .... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695350/how-to-update-the-sale-order-line-in-odoo9openerp-for-eqpend-quantity-price)

Comment: If i understand you and your requirement correct, i don't see why my answer or your variant (eqp_card) isn't working. Either your method `_fix_tax_included_price` is written in old api or new api style, the value for partner_id should be in context. Can you edit your question and add this method?

Comment: I have not coded `_fix_tax_included_price` this method i am just using it as it passes the context to pricelist & I cannot find this method in sale|pricelist files or else i would have posted it. As per me it is most probably in old api as most of the code in pricelist is in old api.

Comment: `eqp_card` is type `Boolean`, is that an issue ? I don't understand why is it not working & `def product_id_change(self):` method starts with `if self.order_id.partner_id.eqp_card == True:`.

Comment: When i print `self.order_id.partner_id.eqp_card` in sale order line it is `True`.. and when i pass it in the context and it passes the `id`.Why is this so?

Comment: did you change the name for context to `eqp_card`? seems `partner_id` is overriden later. so try out `.with_context(eqp_card=self.order_id.partner_id.eqp_card)`.

Comment: Yes the output at pricelist end is `None`.

Comment: This is very werid.. when i tried to do `eqp_card=self.order_id.partner_id.eqp_card` before passing the context and pass the context like this `.with_context(eqp_card)`, it give me an error saying `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable` & the normal way it is giving me `None` at the pricelist end.

Comment: Hey can I pass values in context for e.g. `if eqp_card == True` pass the value `1` and `if eqp_card == False` pass value `2` . Ill do the computation according to that in pricelist.

Comment: that would change nothing.

Comment: but can values be passes ?

Comment: as i said, that would change nothing. True and False are values, too...